# How to insert a paragraph (which works only in the "ltxmdf" class) into a class "book" document?

Tags: boxes, theorems, mdframed, books

I have the next document (in ltxmdf class ), which compiles perfectly (view image).

I want put in a document book class. ¿is posibble?.

I've already tried but get 4 errors. How do I change the header ?.

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[parskip=false,11pt]{ltxmdf}
\newcommand\Loadedframemethod{default}
\usepackage[framemethod=\Loadedframemethod]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}
\newrobustcmd\ExampleText{%
An \textit{inhomogeneous linear} differential equation has the form
\begin{align}
L[v ] = f,
\end{align}
where $L$ is a linear differential operator, $v$ is
the dependent variable, and $f$ is a given non-zero
function of the independent variables alone.
}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{theo}[section]
\newenvironment{theo}[1][]{%
\stepcounter{theo}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheo};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
}{\end{mdframed}}
\begin{theo}[Inhomogeneous Linear]
\ExampleText
\end{theo}
\begin{theo}
\ExampleText
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

[image: Text output document "ltxmdf" in dvi format]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only small changes in preamble are needed:

```
\documentclass[parskip=false,11pt]{book}
    \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\ExampleText{%
    An \textit{inhomogeneous linear} differential equation has the form
    \begin{align}
    L[v ] = f,
    \end{align}
    where $L$ is a linear differential operator, $v$ is
    the dependent variable, and $f$ is a given non-zero
    function of the independent variables alone.
                        }
```

Other part of code is the same as in your MWE. Also the same is obtained picture of theorems.

Comment: Thank you. It has been very useful. 
Moreover, what is MWE?

Comment: Minimal Working Example (MWE) is the smallest possible complete code, which you can copy in your computer, compile and will show your problem. With this , what is your problem. In this context your code in question is MWE.

Comment: Oh I see. I have another question: 
How do each theorem and equation is enumerated according to the chapter, section or subsection ?. 
What would the headline?

Comment: Do you mean that numner of theorem is composed for example as `<section>. <theorem>`? In this case see example on the second page of `mdframed` documentation.

Comment: Try something like this: `\newmdtheoremenv[<mdframedoptions>]{<envname>}[<numberedlike>]{<caption>}[<within>]`, page 15, section 8: Theorems (mdframed documentation)

Comment: I put:
    \newmdtheoremenv{theo}{Theorem}[section]
But I get error.

Comment: To solve this you problem through comment  is very difficult. Please, ask new question, on which the people can suggest solutions to your problem. Similar definition work fine to me.